# ai movement and animation c# unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn to make a simple 2d game but I have a problem. I have an AI that can walk in a random direction but the animation does not change. While moving, the animation is in idle animation.

```
void Start () {

    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    myrigbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    waitCounter = walkTime;
    walkCounter = walkTime;

    ChooseDirections();
}


void Update () {


    if (isWalking)
    {

        walkCounter -= Time.deltaTime;

        switch (walkdirection)
        {
            case 0:
                myrigbody.velocity = new Vector2(0, moveSpeed);
                break;
            case 1:
                myrigbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);
                break;
            case 2:
                myrigbody.velocity = new Vector2(0, -moveSpeed);
                break;
            case 3:
                myrigbody.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, 0);
                break;
        }

        if (walkCounter < 0)
        {
            isWalking = false;
            waitCounter = waitTime;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        waitCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        myrigbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;

        if (waitCounter < 0)
        {
            ChooseDirections();
        }
    }
}

public void ChooseDirections()
{
    walkdirection = Random.Range(0,4);
    isWalking = true;
    walkCounter = walkTime;
}
```

Is there a way to make my AI animation face where he is going? It seems he won't follow the blend tree.

Answer (score 0):

Use Animator Controller; [See this link](https://www.studica.com/blog/unity-tutorial-animator-controllers).

if you're working on the top-down game and you want to make your Game Object face where he going, [this link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/654222/make-sprite-look-at-vector2-in-unity-2d-1.html) can help you.